# Is there a way to expose route params outside <Route> component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

If I have something like this:

```
<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <App />
</ConnectedRouter>
```

My routes config looks like:

```
export default [{
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    main: Home
}, 
{
    path: '/:someId',
    exact: true,
    main: Profile
},
{
    path: '*',
    main: NotFound
}];
```

Where app is just a wrapper of the routes and other components like:

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      {routes.map((route, i) => <Route exact key={i} component={route.main} path={route.path}/>)}
    </Switch>
    <AnotherComponent {...this.props} />
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Is there a way for AnotherComponent to use match.params or to expose those? I already tried wrapping the component with *withRouter* and also adding it as a Route with no path to match like:

```
<Route component={AnotherComponent} />
```

And when the route is /:someId it does render both Profile and AnotherComponent, but match.params for AnotherComponent are empty :/.

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React router will only return params if you have a path on the Route. You can pass down the params from your top level . Have that component render  inside of it. It will have access to the params. As for any other time, you need to be doing:

```
<Route  path="/:someId" component={AnotherComponent} />
```

If you want it to actually get that param!

Only children underneath the `Route` component can access the params. You should be building your app in such a way that only the component inside that route needs its params.

Comment: I understand, the problem is that I need this component to be always present. At first is "hidden" but when navigating to /:someId, I need to initialize it with the information of this id, and then have it actively present throughout the app, even if the route changes.

Comment: Then render it with a question mark at the end :) `<Route  path="/:someId?" component={AnotherComponent} />` That will render it with or without that id!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Edit: You can use https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch directly these days.

###### Original Answer

You can use `matchPath`

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

 //----
const { pathname } = useLocation()

const params =  matchPath(pathname, { path:"/:someId" })
 //----
```

Comment: Can even use `useRouteMatch` to simplify it further
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch

Comment: Thanks Byrant, updated my answer based on that.

Answer (score -2):

You can just wrap that component with it's own Route component like this:

```
...  
<Route path="/cameras/:camera/">
  <CameraName />
</Route>
...

// this is so the camera name can be fetched from the route.
const CameraName = () => {
  let { camera } = useParams();
  return <div>{camera}</div>;
};
```