# React - get parameters from route path in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I tried to find it, but I couldn't do it. I tested many results but the effects were disappointing.

So I have this structure of application:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Menu/>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/business/:id" element={<SomePage />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In `SomePage` component I can use `useParams` and I see this `id` like object `{ id: 6 }` - it's fine and makes sense. But I have a case when I have to extract this id in `Menu` component and `useParams` returns:

```
{
  *: "business/6"
}
```

But I would like to get object:

```
{
  id: 6
}
```

I tried to use `matchPath`, `useMatch`, `useResolvedPath`, and others but I didn't have any special effects.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782774/is-there-a-way-to-expose-route-params-outside-route-component `matchPath` should work. Why do you need unrelated param in the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are rendering `Menu` outside a `Routes` component then use the [`useMatch`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match) hook to check if there is a match for the `"/business/:id"` path. If there is a match then `useMatch` returns a `Match` object that has a `params` property, otherwise it returns null (*so use a guard-clause or null-check before accessing into the return value*).

You could alternatively create a layout route component that renders `Menu` along with an `Outlet` and render it within the `Routes` component and use the `useParams` hook to access the `params` object.

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route, Outlet, useParams, useMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const MenuStandalone = () => {
  const match = useMatch("/business/:id");

  console.log("MenuStandalone", match?.params);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>MenuStandalone</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

const MenuLayout = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  console.log("MenuLayout", params);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>MenuLayout</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

const SomePage = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  console.log("SomePage", params);

  return <h1>SomePage</h1>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MenuStandalone />

      <Routes>
        <Route element={<MenuLayout />}>
          <Route path="/business/:id" element={<SomePage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-get-parameters-from-route-path-in-another-component]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your answer makes sense. I dreaded that I would have a problem with access to `useParams` in components outside <Routes>. With useMatch is the problem that I have to know current path to find this `id`, but it also works with regexp: `useMatch("/business/:id/*")` so it will be fine for `/business/6/settings` => `{*: '/settings', id: "6"}`.

Answer (score 1):

According to official react router documentation [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) hook can only access the params of a `Route` within the `Routes` component. The problem is the `Menu` component is outside of the Routes component.

just wrap the `<Menu />` component like below and try.

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/business/:id" element={<SomePage />} />
    <Route element={<Menu />} />
 </Routes>
```

also see:
[Get id using useParams hook in functional component - react router dom v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025652/get-id-using-useparams-hook-in-functional-component-react-router-dom-v6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) from the documentation